# Moodle doesn't open files from one specific course

Tags: moodle

the enterprise I work for owns a Moodle website with many courses. In all of them, we attach many files .doc or .pdf, so that users can download and read them. The problem is, in one of them - without apparent reason - users can't get the files. When clicking on a file, the website displays a message that goes more or less like this "You are already logged in as yourself. Exit and log as another user to see the file". Even if you do what the message is asking, nothing changes: you still get the same message and the files can't be downloaded or opened at all. **And just in this specific course!**

[image: Message print]

Note: I'm not trying to access the log in page while already logged, as some people in other forums suggested. I'm trying to ***OPEN/DOWNLOAD a file***, just that! I have to be logged in order to see the links to the files, so there is no call for going to the login page again.

Comment: Can you search for the string in the code and tell me the string id. It will be something like `$string['stringid'] = 'Voce ja...'`

Comment: If only I knew wich page displays this code.. :/ These readymade websites can be a real mess.

Comment: yes, search for the string 'Voce ja...' it will give you a string id and then you can see where the code is.

Comment: Turn on the `debugstringids`. Also if you turn the errors all the way up it will show the line that throws that error.

Comment: @RussellEngland, I would gladly give you the string id, but I don't know where it is located. I've searched on database and on files and didn't find it. Tell me wich file has this code and I'll fetch the string id for you. Please note that I'm not an expert. I'm new to moodle and don't have a clue of how to fix this. Thanks in advance

Comment: @JakubKania I turned it on and saved it, but when I refresh the page, it goes back to "Don't show errors and warnings" option :/

Comment: @JakubKania I managed to turn debugging on, I enabled every message, take a look at what the debugger returned to me: http://prntscr.com/byndd0 I understand that none of these are error messages. What's going on? :/

Comment: Does the site has guest access enabled? Maybe the course has some custom plugins? If  you know some programming then you can trace where the message comes from by editing the line about it in login/index.php to throw an exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My host manager disabled cache from the server and problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Have a read through this - https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=331032

Switch on debugging - https://docs.moodle.org/31/en/Debugging

Then try again, do you get an error message about `open_basedir`?

(Also for reference, the language is Brazilian Portuguese (pt_br), the string id is `alreadyloggedin` and the file is `error.php` - the string id is only used once in the file `/login/index.php`)

Comment: Yes, know, I am Brazilian xD I don't get many answers from brazilian forums, so I decided to go abroad. As for turing the Debugging on, I did it a number of times and it doesn't work. Here's how the config file looks: http://prntscr.com/bz1h9v Here's my Debugging settings (all set to yes, show all the messages possible): http://prntscr.com/bz1ib5 As for that base_opendir, thing, it appears on phpinfo, but with no value: http://prntscr.com/bz1jba

Comment: In my php.ini file, I found this suspicious setting: extension_dir = "/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525" Could it be the reason whe debugging isn't working?

Comment: @Educative The debugging doesn't work because there is no error.

Comment: @JakubKania, if there is no error, how is it possible **no one**, be it me or the students, can access the files? If I'm doing something wrong, then 100 people must be doing the same.

Comment: @Educative You don't understand. It may be an wrong you're redirected to a login page but debug won't help you because the message you see is not an error.

Comment: @JakubKania Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: @Educative We don't know what it is. I told you in the comments above how I would debug it. throw an exception and trace it to the source. If you don't know php I'm afraid you will have to find someone that does.

Comment: PHP is not a problem. Thank you for your suggestion